# overlay two qplots (smoother and confidence intervals) in R

Tags: r, spline, confidence-interval

I want to plot two sets of data and show the data, the smoother and the confidence interval for each set but both sets in one graph.

```
plotdata <- data.frame(x=1:10, y1=runif(10, min=0, max=10), y2=runif(10, min=10, max=20))
qplot(x, y1, data=plotdata, geom=c("point", "smooth"), method="rlm")
qplot(x, y2, data=plotdata, geom=c("point", "smooth"), method="rlm")
```

is there a way to combine these two qplots or to extract the qplot information and plot it with ggplot?
All solutions I found so far are only for single lines, points etc but not for the confidence intervals. Thanks!

Comment: Any reason it has to be done with qplot not the default interface?

Comment: no, that was the solution I found

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have the same plot with ggplot

E.g: the first plot:

```
plotdata %>% ggplot( aes(x, y1)) + geom_point() + geom_smooth(method = "rlm")
```

and you can play from now on with the more flexible `ggplot`

Answer (score 2):

You can use `gather` from package `tidyr` to transform the data frame into the long format. This new data frame is suitable for the use with `ggplot`.

```
library(tidyr)
library(ggplot2)
library(MASS)

pd <- gather(plotdata, set, value, -x)

ggplot(pd, aes(x = x, y = value, colour = set, shape = set)) +
  geom_point() +
  geom_smooth(method = rlm)
```

The plot displays the data for both `y1` and `y2`.

[image]